# Which takes precendence: Don't Repeat Yourself or the Single Responsibility Principle?

Tags: c#, oop, dry, single-responsibility-principle

Whilst upgrading some old code, I've found a situation in which these two OO principles seem to be in conflict with one another.

Consider the following pseudocode (it's a simplified version of what I've encountered):

```
int numberOfNewRecords;
int numberOfOldRecords;
int numberOfUndefinedRecords;

void ColourAndCount()
{
    foreach(Row row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        switch(row.Cells["Status"])
        {
            case: "Old"
                row.BackColor = Color.Red;
                numberOfOldRecords++;
                break;
            case: "New"
                row.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                numberOfNewRecords++;
                break;
            default:
                row.BackColor = Color.White;
                numberOfUndefinedRecords++;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This code does two things: it tally's up the number of records by their status, and it also colourises each row, again by their status. It's messy, but since these two operations have (thus far) always been called at the same time, it hasn't caused any problems and has made maintenance requirements like additional Statuses easy to add.

Nevertheless, the Single Responsibility Principle tells me I should split this into two separate methods:

(Edit) Minor note: I've just realized I may be misusing the term "Single Responsibility Principle" here, which as I understand it refers to classes. What's the term for the "one operation per method" design pattern?

```
int numberOfNewRecords;
int numberOfOldRecords;
int numberOfUndefinedRecords;

void Count()
{
    foreach(Row row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        switch(row.Cells["Status"])
        {
            case: "Old"
                numberOfOldRecords++;
                break;
            case: "New"
                numberOfNewRecords++;
                break;
            default:
                numberOfUndefinedRecords++;
                break;
        }
    }
}

void Colour()
{
    foreach(Row row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        switch(row.Cells["Status"])
        {
            case: "Old"
                row.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
            case: "New"
                row.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                break;
            default:
                row.BackColor = Color.White;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

But this violates Don't Repeat Yourself: the loop and switch statement is duplicated in both methods, and since the most likely upgrade path for this code is the addition of other Statuses, it makes future upgrades more difficult rather than less.

I having trouble working out the most elegant way to refactor this, so I felt it best to ask the community in case there's something obvious I'm missing. How would you address this situation?

(EDIT)

I came up with one possible solution, but it looks to me like an example of over-engineering a simple problem, (and it doesn't really solve the original Single Responsibility problem).

```
struct Status
{
    public string Name,
    public int Count,
    public Color Colour,
}

Dictionary<string, Status> StatiiDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
void Initialise()
{
    StatiiDictionary.Add(new Status("New", 0, Color.Red));
    StatiiDictionary.Add(new Status("Old", 0, Color.Blue));
    StatiiDictionary.Add(new Status("Undefined", 0, Color.White));
}

void ColourAndCountAllRows()
{
    foreach(Row row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        CountRow(row, StatiiDictionary);
        ColourRow(row, StatiiDictionary);
    }
}

void CountRow(Row row, Dictionary<string, Status> StatiiDictionary)
{
    StatiiDictionary[row.Cells["Status"]].Count++; 
}

void ColourRow(Row row, Dictionary<string, Status> StatiiDictionary)
{
    row.BackColour = StatiiDictionary[row.Cells["Status"]].Colour;
}
```

Comment: As long as code similar to the original code is used at a single place, doing a switch inside the loop might be acceptable. However, if you might add some other operations like counting selected rows by type, then it would make sense to refactor the code using idea from Matt answer.

Answer (score 6):

There are lots of programming rules that need to be violated from time to time for pragmatic reasons.  In your case, I'd agree that DRY and SRP appear to be competing so I would suggest two criteria to decide the winner:

1. What would it mean for the code to obey each one.
2. What would it mean for the application to obey each one.

In this case, the inefficiency of enumerating the rows of the grid twice seems to be the overriding factor to me and DRY would win out **in this particular case**.  In some other case it may be the other way around.

It would be worth adding a comment to explain the decision you made and why so it's clear to anyone looking at the code later.  This is exactly the sort of thing that comments should be used for, i.e. **why** the code is doing what it's doing rather than just what it's doing.

Answer (score 6):

Design patterns inform decisions. They are not to be followed religiously. They help you add properties to your code that makes it easier to maintain. Following every design pattern will result in **gross overengineering**, which is far worse than neglecting a certain principle.

On the face of it, it seems reasonable to join up the multiple operations into one iterator. This is more efficient than iterating twice but it limits you from performing both of the operations, not one or the other. So you use the resulting properties of the viable implementation to make a judgement call about which is best. If you thought it was important to apply the operations individually, you would feel ok about repeating yourself.

There is a solution that will satisfy both, but the problem is that it would be very overengineered. The properties you want your code to have to respect both DRY and SRP with the efficiency benefits of the first solution are:

- Allow you to apply an operation individually - SRP
- Not repeat iteration over the rows twice - DRY/efficiency
- Not repeat the same switch statement twice - DRY/efficiency

In similar pseudocode, using a Java-style approach instead of a functional one, you can meet these criteria with the following solution:

```
public abstract class RowOperation {
    public void apply(string status, Row row) {
        switch(status)
        {
            case: "Old"
                this.OldCase(row);
                break;
            case: "New"
                this.NewCase(row);
                break;
            default:
                this.OtherCase(row);
                break;
        }
    }
    abstract void OldCase(Row);
    abstract void NewCase(Row);
    abstract void OtherCase(Row);
}

public class ColorRow implements RowOperation {
    private static final ColorCells OP = new ColorCells();

    private ColorCells(){}

    // This operation isn't stateful so we use a singleton :D
    public static RowOperation getInstance() {
        return this.OP
    }

    public void OldCase(row) {
        row.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }

    public void NewCase(row) {
        row.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    }

    public void OtherCase(row) {
        row.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
}

public class CountRow implements CellOperation {
    public int oldRows = 0;
    public int newRows = 0;
    public int otherRows= 0;

    // This operation is stateful so we use the contructor
    public CountRow() {}

    public void OldCase(Row row) {
        oldRows++;
    }

    public void NewCase(Row row) {
        newRows++;
    }

    public void OtherCase(Row row) {
        otherRows++;
    }
}

// For each row in the grid we will call each operation
// function with the row status and the row
void UpdateRows(Grid grid, RowOperation[] operations)
{
    foreach(Row row in grid.Rows)
    {
        string status = row.Cells["Status"]

        foreach(RowOperation op in operations)
        {
            op.apply(status, row)
        }
    }
}
```

And then you could apply multiple ops to the rows in one iteration, adding new operations as you need them

```
RowOperations[] ops = {
    ColorRow.getInstance(),
    new CountRows()    
};

UpdateRows(dataGrid1, ops);
```

But as you'll notice, implementing every design pattern you have read about leads to this overengineered solution. I even skipped a level of class hierarchy here, and it's still pretty bad. The code has all the benefits of the design patterns respected here, but the question is, in the context of the application, do you really need all of these properties? The answer is probably no.

Comment: There are many good idea in your "over engineered" code but if the code for each case is simple, you might use an `Action<Row>` instead so you don't need to write as much extra code.

Comment: What I dislike from you code is that if you have multiple operations, you would repeat the dispatching every time. This is where a composite operation would make sense. For example, the `OldCase` method of the composite would call the `OldCase` method of each item in the list.